# Framework script in esp8266 webserver

Tags: html, arduino, frameworks, esp8266

(sory my english, it is not my fist language)

I'm trying to make a webserver to control the ESP8266 (with arduino IDE).

I'm using this code to put my html file in arduino IDE:

```
const char MAIN_page[] PROGMEM = R"=====( "my HTML file" )=====";
```

This works very well with a simple html code...

I want to use the Phonon Framework to improve my webserver.

I create the html file im my pc and everything works great.

but

When I put the html code in ESP8266 the html crashes.

In my tests (put the code part-by-part) I realized that the error occurs when I put the phonon-core.min.js

```
    <script>
```

(the code is too long to put here, but it is this: 
https://github.com/quark-dev/Phonon-Framework/blob/master/dist/js/phonon-core.min.js)

```
    </script>
```

Do not appear any error in browser, but in the html elements is like it is empty.

I think there is some incompatibility, but I do not know what it is.

Thank you so much for any help.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to serve web pages, especially with multiple files for JS/CSS/etc, you're far better off uploading them to the ESP8266 under a SPIFFS filesystem, and serving them up using that. You can find an example of that [here](https://github.com/esp8266/Arduino/tree/master/libraries/ESP8266WebServer/examples/FSBrowser)

I suspect somewhere the HTML is getting corrupted in your code since you're pasting it in, and something somewhere doesn't get escaped properly, leading the browser to drop an element. You could verify this by looking at the raw HTML returned outside a browser, something should be off.